# How to filter objects based on Foreign key

Tags: django, filter, foreign-keys, annotate

I have 2 model classes called product and product_category

```
class product_category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=280, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(product_category, related_name='type_category', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

In the views.py this is how I usually load all the products related to a single user

```
all_category = product.objects.filter(user=user)
```

but what I am struggling to filter is the product list based on the category they are in.

As you can see, product_type is optional, so some products might not have any type. Those products should be listed at the end of the list.

This is how I want to display it on the website

- category-1

  - product-1
  - product-2
  - product-3
- category-2

  - product-4
  - product-5
  - product-6
- category-3

  - product-7
- product-8
- product-9
- product-10

how can I achieve this?

EDIT 1.

Thanks to [neeraj-kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4626788/neeraj-kumar), I found what I was looking for.

here's his answer with a bit of 
 in the code to see the result more clearly.

views.py

```
    all_category = product_category.objects.filter(user=user)
    product_exclude = product.objects.exclude(id__in=all_category.values_list('type_category__id',flat=True)).filter(user=user)
```

template.html

```
{% for cat in all_category %}
    {% with products=cat.type_category.all %}
        <h5>{{cat.category_name}}</h5>
        {% if products|length %}
            {% for pro in products %}
                <p>{{ pro }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <br>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
{% for pro in product_exclude %}
    <p>{{ pro }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_category = product_category.objects.filter(user=user)
product_exclude = product.objects.exclude(id__in=all_category.values_list('type_category__id',flat=True)
```

pass both var in template

```
{% for cat in all_category %}
   {% with products = cat.type_category.all %}
       {% if products|length %}
            {% for pro in products %}
                {{ pro }}
            {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}
   {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
{% for pro in product_exclude %}
     {{ pro }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hey, I found a bug in this... if there are 4 categories, and if only 3 (or less) category have any product in them, it is not filtering product_exclude... i.e. product_exclude is empty, even if there are many products with no category... how do can we solve this?

Comment: It's not working for some reason. I feel the problem is in .exclude(). Because when I am replacing .exclude with .filter, it is showing a list of items which we want to be excluded. How can we get rid of this bug? any Idea?